# Colorbox "This content failed to load." error

Tags: drupal, load, colorbox

I need to load a subscription form with colorbox on page load.Colorbox opens on page load but inside I only see an error message "This content failed to load.".
 Here is the code that I use

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.colorbox5').colorbox({open:true, href:'div#content5'});  
    });
    ....
```

**HTML**

```
   <body>
       <div style="display:none;">
        <div id="content5" class="colorbox5">
        ... my form here
        </div>
       </div>
```

Can anybody please help me to solve this problem?
(I'm using Drupal)

Answer (score 0):

Looking [here](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) under "content type", you need to tell colorbox it's displaying something inline. So, I think you need this: `$('.colorbox5').colorbox({open:true, href:'div#content5', inline:true,});`

Comment: So what was the solution?